# Smooth way to iteratre through two lists JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, collections, lambda

I have two sets of Objects, first stores Labels and the second one stores Buttons. Every label is connected to its own button i.e `label11` is placed on `btn11` and so on. I want to change visibility of labels if I click its button. I managed to do this in this way:

```
    btn11.setOnAction(x->label11.setVisible(true));
    btn12.setOnAction(x->label12.setVisible(true));
    btn21.setOnAction(x->label21.setVisible(true));
    btn22.setOnAction(x->label22.setVisible(true));
    btn111.setOnAction(x->label111.setVisible(true));
    btn112.setOnAction(x->label112.setVisible(true));
    btn121.setOnAction(x->label121.setVisible(true));
    btn122.setOnAction(x->label122.setVisible(true));
```

Doing this way I have to write every single line one by one which makes my code unnecessary long and hard to read.I tried placing them into two lists but couldn't find a way to iterate through two lists in one loop. 
So far I managed to create something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<listOfButtons.size();i++){
        listOfButtons.get(i).setOnAction(x->listOfLabels.get(i).setVisible(true));
    }
```

But I'm getting error which says that variables in lambda expressions should be final.
I'd be glad for any help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a plain `for` loop and an array?

Comment: I did, but can't find way to make it working.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I've edited my post, that was the only one idea I came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the values you need to a `final` variable before using it in the lambda. This will also increase readability.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfButtons.size(); i++) {
    final Button button = listOfButtons.get(i);
    final Label label = listOfLabels.get(i);
    button.setOnAction(x -> label.setVisible(true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a "smooth"-er way by utilizing some additional Java 8 functionality instead of the traditional `for` and `final` declarations which should be resolving an issue with `i` and can therefore be fixed with `final int fi = i;` and use the final one instead in your lambda. Or this:

```
IntStream.range(0, buttons.size())
        .forEach(i -> buttons.get(i).setOnAction(e -> labels.get(i).setVisible(true)));
```

Additionally, given your example of poorly named label and button references, I would also suggest you put the pair in a convenience class and a single list of the components.

```
class ButtonLabelPair {
    Button button;
    Label label;
}

List<ButtonPairs> buttonPairs = ...
```

And set the actions like:

```
buttonPairs.forEach(p -> p.button.setOnAction(e -> p.label.setVisible(true)));
```

Or, you could do it in the constructor of the pair:

```
class ButtonLabelPair {
    ...
    public ButtonLabelPair(Button button, Label label) {
        this.button = button;
        this.label = label;
        this.button.setOnAction(e -> this.label.setVisible(true));
    }
}
```